# Auto Scaling Group Reattach Volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ecs, aws-ebs

I have an ECS cluster running one docker container which I want to run for only several hours per day. When the instance does not need to be used I want it to be stopped but I found that I can't stop an instance in ASG because it will get terminated automatically. So when I set the desired count of ASG to 0 my instance is getting terminated and all volumes that were attached to that instance also gets wiped so I lose my data.

I've set the BlockDeviceMappings of my cloud formation template to persist those volumes

`BlockDeviceMappings:
      - DeviceName: '/dev/xvda'
        Ebs:
          DeleteOnTermination: false
      - DeviceName: '/dev/xvdcz'
        Ebs:
          DeleteOnTermination: false`

When instance is terminated I would like to reattach those existing EBS but instead two new separate volumes are created. How could I make it that It reattach to the already existing EBS volumes instead of making new ones of each new ec2 instance creation.

Comment: Why are you using ASG for single instance?, you can use single standalone server  and you can schedule time period  when to stop&start  container and instance as well.